# How many MySQL queries per visit I should normally have?

Tags: plugins

Hi, I have 170 MySQL queries per visit. Is that OK? 
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Per visit, or per page load? If the latter, then no, 170 is insane.

Comment: looking at strictly quantity of queries is somewhat pointless, you can run 100 fast queries in less time than 1 inefficient query. it all depends on what those queries are.

Comment: off-topic: what's the tool in your screenshot?

Comment: @Jesse: P3 Profiler, as noted in infrcl's answer. https://wordpress.org/plugins/p3-profiler/

Answer (score 1):

This is highly contextual. For blank WP site out of the box that would be a lot. For heavy site with multiple plugins (which you do seem to run quite a few of) this might be what it takes.

In general the SQL query is retrieval of data from database. Deciding between "many" or "not many" is more precisely answering questions of:

- is data that is not needed being retrieved?
- can data needed be retrieved in more efficient ways (in bulk with less queries)?
- can part of data be made less needed (with caching for example) and does anything prevent that from being implemented or working as intended if it's already is?

Answer (score 0):

The number of queries maybe irrelevant.

You've used the [P3](https://wordpress.org/plugins/p3-profiler/) plugin to obtain the performance summary. By default, the calculations could be imprecise cause they depend on which pages/posts are analyzed.

The important thing is the time consumption of the queries. You can check the times in wordpress with the [Debug Queries](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-queries/) plugin (you'll need the Debug Bar plugin also). Then you'll have to inspect the slow queries in order to reduce the time by adding indexes, foreingn keys, etc.